# Java Sound not Playing

Tags: java, audio

I know this problem has been queried previously, and I have looked at the responses and tried to implement them, but so far nobody's solutions seem to be working for me. Please can anyone have a look at my code and help me figure out why the program ends instantly, and no sound is played....? thanks in advance

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class SoundPlayer {

    public SoundPlayer() {
    }

    public static void play(String file) {
        File sound = new File(file);
        try {
            String url = sound.toURI().toURL().toString();
            System.out.println(url);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new URL(url)));
            clip.start();
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
        player.play("sounds/1.wav");

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh how strange! I removed clip.start, and Thread.sleep, and now the whole thing works just fine with no exceptions! So, please ignore previous question! :)

Comment: clip.loop(int) is an alternative to clip.start(). So it makes sense that you can drop the latter command. I'm guessing you have other things happening that are keeping the program open, thus allowing the daemon sound thread to continue to execute in the background, and the previous Thread.sleep() was interrupting the main program flow. Hard to know for sure without seeing more of what you coded.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the answer is to include

```
Thread.sleep(1000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a file (a .wav sound file in your case) it is active as long as your code is beign executed so when the execution is over it stops in your case the only code to be executed is to play the .wav file and then the execution is over the sound plays but stops so fast.

The solution as you suggested `Thread.sleep(time)` is there to keep the execution for the time chosen and then it stops and the sound file with it. You can use a `while` loop to hold the execution running for as long as the there is code to execute and that means the audio file will play along with it (you have used `clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);` )

Answer (score 0):

Your program is an example of multi-threaded coding. The command `clip.start()` launches a new, concurrently running thread and then proceeds to the next line of code without pause. Your thread then sets the loop flag, and finishes.

Meanwhile, the concurrent "play" thread is executing. But this thread has been given "daemon" status. Regular threads will keep a program running until they are finished, but "daemon" status threads will allow themselves to be halted if there are no regular threads alive. So, when the "main" thread is done, the audio-playback thread also quits.

API info about [threads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html).

When a `Clip` launches a new thread with the `start()` method, the thread is automatically given `daemon` status.

It baffles me, though, that I cannot find *any* API documentation about the status of the new thread launched by `Clip`. Nor is there mention of this in Oracle's [Playing Back Audio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html) tutorial. So you, and countless other people using the `Clip` object for the first time can hardly be faulted for being mystified when this happens.

Comment: Thank you! This all makes complete sense. Now I want to stop the loop elsewhere in the program and, as such,  have called .interrupt on that particular thread which contains the SoundPlayer). It throws An InterruptedException, which is understandable, and not a problem, however I wonder if there is a way of implementing it with .wait() and .notify() which would get around an exception. Only problem is, clip.wait() throws its own exception - IllegalMonitorStateException. It might not matter at all, but I am wondered if you had any thoughts? :)

Comment: By far the easiest way to stop a clip is to just call clip.stop() directly on the clip variable itself. The Clip API won't allow you to change the number of loops (loop count int is "final"). If the goal is let the sound play out one final time that would require implementing LineListener. Back to orig question: it's a matter of making the clip variable reachable by the portion of the code that "knows when it's time" to stop the clip. My preference is to use "loose coupling" patterns where possible. Maybe easiest is to make some sort of public "stopClip(clip)" method. How you ID it can vary.